# JTAG Daisy chain debugging using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, embedded, stm32, jtag, segger-jlink

I have 1 STM32H7 and 2 STM32F4 on my board. I am using a Jlink debug probe using which I would like to daisy chain and do the debugging on one of the aforementioned MCUs. I could configure almost everything within the GDB SEGGER J-Link debugging configuration menu, however, I do not see any option to set IRpre and DRpre registers in GDB SEGGER J-Link debugging configuration menu in eclipse. Can someone please guide me? Thanks

I tried invoking JlinkExe to set the IRpre and DRpre registers but I failed. I would like to know if anyone has done GDB JTAG Daisy Chain debugging using Eclipse.

Comment: Found a solution myself. Adding the following argument -jtagconf 18,4 (18, and 4 are substitutes for IRPre, DRPre on my board for daisy chaining) in the "Other options" under the "Debugger" within the "Debug Configurations" resolved the problem. Now, I can directly flash and add breakpoints. Happy if this helps someone. Cheers!